# I lost the windows where it shows each layer and the tab with all of the icons including modifiers

Tags: modeling, interface

I was trying to click something in the top right-hand corner of my screen, however, when doing so I accidentally clicked something else that got rid of where I can see my layers and also my modifiers. How do I get those screens back?
[image: my screen] [image: I want to get this back]

I want to get this back ^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's the [Outliner](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.0/editors/outliner/introduction.html) and [Properties](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.0/editors/properties_editor.html) editor areas.  Here's how to [open new areas (Splitting)](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.0/interface/window_system/areas.html) after which you can switch the [Editor Types](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.0/editors/index.html) to Outliner and Properties.

[image]

This answer is for Blender 3.0 (the current version), and may be different if you're using something else.